# CMake linking error

Tags: hyperlink, cmake

I have a problem with CMake.

I want to compile a file receive certain errors when linking.

Here is my error log:

```
[ 30%] Built target thecore
[ 37%] Built target sql
[ 44%] Built target poly
[ 50%] Built target game
Linking CXX executable db_32
CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/src/Main.cpp.o: In function `Start()':
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:373: undefined reference to `PlayerHB::Initialize()'
CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/src/Main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `PlayerHB::PlayerHB()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::CBlockCountry()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:84: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::Load()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::~CBlockCountry()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `PlayerHB::~PlayerHB()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:74: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::~CBlockCountry()'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/Main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `PlayerHB::~PlayerHB()'
CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/src/ClientManager.cpp.o: In function `CClientManager::BlockException(tBlockException*)':
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManager.cpp:4248: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::DelBlockException(char const*)'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManager.cpp:4263: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::SendBlockExceptionOne(CPeer*, char const*, unsigned char)'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManager.cpp:4243: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::AddBlockException(char const*)'
CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/src/ClientManager.cpp.o: In function `CClientManager::ProcessPackets(CPeer*)':
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManager.cpp:2636: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::SendBlockedCountryIp(CPeer*)'
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManager.cpp:2637: undefined reference to `CBlockCountry::SendBlockException(CPeer*)'
CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/src/ClientManagerPlayer.cpp.o: In function `CClientManager::PutPlayerCache(SPlayerTable*)':
/atharia_svn/server/db/src/ClientManagerPlayer.cpp:193: undefined reference to `PlayerHB::Put(unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [db/db_32] Error code 1

Stop in /atharia_svn/Build.
*** [db/CMakeFiles/db_32.dir/all] Error code 1

Stop in /atharia_svn/Build.
*** [all] Error code 1

Stop in /atharia_svn/Build.
```

I do not understand why is not running, when compiling the makefile under gcc49 not receive any error.

Everything works perfection.

This is CMakeLists.txt from object linking:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

MESSAGE(STATUS "compilerVersion=${COMPILER}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${DB_OUTPUT_DIR})
set(exe db_32)

MESSAGE(STATUS "svnVersion=${svnVersion}")
include_directories("../../extern/boost-1.43.0")        #Boost
include_directories("../../extern/mysql-5.6.23")        #Mysql

link_directories(
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/libthecore
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/libsql
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/libpoly
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Build/libgame
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../extern/mysql-5.6.23
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS_CXX}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${ADDITIONAL_LINKER_FLAGS}")

add_executable (${exe}
                src/Config.cpp
                src/NetBase.cpp
                src/Peer.cpp
                src/PeerBase.cpp
                src/Main.cpp
                src/Lock.cpp
                src/DBManager.cpp
                src/Cache.cpp
                src/LoginData.cpp
                src/ClientManager.cpp
                src/ClientManagerPlayer.cpp
                src/ClientManagerLogin.cpp
                src/ClientManagerBoot.cpp
                src/ClientManagerParty.cpp
                src/ClientManagerGuild.cpp
                src/GuildManager.cpp
                src/PrivManager.cpp
                src/MoneyLog.cpp
                src/ItemAwardManager.cpp
                src/ClientManagerEventFlag.cpp
                src/Marriage.cpp src/Monarch.cpp
                src/ItemIDRangeManager.cpp
                src/ClientManagerHorseName.cpp
                src/version.cpp
                src/AuctionManager.cpp
                src/ProtoReader.cpp
                src/CsvReader.cpp
                )

add_definitions(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${exe} PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -static)
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINK_DYNAMIC_C_FLAGS)       # remove -Wl,-Bdynamic
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINK_DYNAMIC_CXX_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS)         # remove -fPIC
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS)    # remove -rdynamic
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${exe} pthread libthecore.a libsql.a libmysqlclient.a libpoly.a libgame.a)
```

And here is the principal CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(game)
enable_language(C)
set(COMPILER "g++49") #Required


set(ADDITIONAL_FLAGS_CXX "-O2 -pipe -mtune=i686 -g")
set(ADDITIONAL_LINKER_FLAGS "-O2 -pipe -mtune=i686 -g")


add_subdirectory(libthecore)
add_subdirectory(libsql)
add_subdirectory(libpoly)
add_subdirectory(libgame)
#add_subdirectory(liblua)
#add_subdirectory(game)
add_subdirectory(db)

set(GAME_OUTPUT_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bin/freebsd_release)
set(DB_OUTPUT_DIR    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bin/freebsd_release)
```

I tried 24 hours to resolve this error, if anyone has idea and can help me please do.

Best Regards.

Comment: With gcc49 , and with defaullt makefiles all work.

Comment: build with make VERBOSE=1 to get the command used to link the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, has a linking error. I changed CFLAGS witc -std=c++14